# Main Image isn't resizing properly

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my site (left side) and when you resize the browser window, it doesn't respond.  However, once you refresh the image then fills the entire space.  Any thoughts on getting it to respond correctly?

Site: splitblog.squarespace.com

HTML

```
<figure class="content-fill main-image"><img {@|image-meta}></figure>
```

CSS

```
.main-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-1000;
}
```

Comment: give image 100% width http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/b8t5E/1/

Comment: on your blog you have fixed width of 953px on the image itself

Answer (score 0):

I see that the image width is set on the image element and is set dynamically via js.

you must force 100% width to the image too.

```
.main-image img{
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the aspect ratio the same when the browser is resized.  How would I keep the aspect ratio the same?

Comment: it lose aspect ratio even in the actual situation.
You can add **height: auto!important** but in this case the image will become smaller in height too.
There are some limits you can decide to block at a certain point and make it static.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-image img {
width: 953px !important;
height: 1430px !important;
}
```

you have messed up with scroll bar, changes for overflow

```
.side-right {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .side-right {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```